# Stable homotopy groups of $Sp(2n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

What are the stable homotopy groups of the symplectic groups $Sp(2n)$?  Is there a reference which contains a detailed treatment?

Answer (score 8):

The stable range for $\pi_k(\mathrm{Sp}(2n))$ is $k \leq 8n + 1$. In this case we have
$$\pi_k(\mathrm{Sp}(2n)) \cong \begin{cases} \Bbb Z, & k \equiv 3, 7 \pmod 8, \\ \Bbb Z/2, & k = 4, 5 \pmod 8, \\ 0, & k \equiv 0, 1, 2, 6 \pmod 8. \end{cases}$$
This was first determined by Bott:

> Bott, Raoul. [*The stable homotopy of the classical groups*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970106). Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 70, No. 2 (Sep., 1959), pp. 313-337.

For more about homotopy groups of $\mathrm{Sp}(2n)$, see the following article:

> Mimura, Mamoru and Toda, Hiroshi. [*Homotopy groups of symplectic groups*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/kyoto-journal-of-mathematics/volume-3/issue-2/Homotopy-groups-of-symplectic-groups/10.1215/kjm/1250524819.full). J. Math. Kyoto Univ. Volume 3, Number 2 (1963), 251-273.